# How to blur a subregion of an image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, blur

I have a picture of a scene and I want to blur few portions of it.
how can I do it using Guassianblur in opencv python.[I want the result as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnAw8.png)

Comment: `img[y1:y2, x1:x2] = cv2.GaussianBlur(img[y1:y2, x1:x2], ...)` should do the trick.